# Converting a Object[] array to an string[] array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have many ways to do it but still want to know is there any offical API to convert object[] to string[] With null checked? Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have a method to convert an `object` to a `string` (or `int`) with null check, then you can use the [Array.ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) to convert an `object[]` to a `string[]` (or `int[]`):

```
object[] input = ...;
string[] result = Array.ConvertAll<object, string>(input, ConvertObjectToString);
```

```csharp
string ConvertObjectToString(object obj)
{
    return obj?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

If you want to skip items in the `object[]` array when converting to a `string[]`, a more convenient approach might be using the extension methods of the [Enumerable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx):

```
object[] input = ...;
string[] result = input.Where(x => x != null)
                       .Select(x => x.ToString())
                       .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 45):

You could just run a simple conversion on it using the ConvertAll method in the Array class and a lambda on the object itself.

```
object[] inputArray = new object[10];
string[] resultArray = Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, x => x.ToString());
```

Comment: Depending on how you have your dependencies setup you might need `System.Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, x => x.ToString());`

Comment: Make sure that no objects contain `null`, else you have an exception.

Comment: Question x:
`System.Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, x => x?.ToString());`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extension method that allows the choice of including/excluding nulls, and what value to use to replace null if included.

```
public static class ObjectArrayExtensions
{
    public static string[] ToStringArray(this object[] array, bool includeNulls = false, string nullValue = "")
    {
        IEnumerable<object> enumerable = array;
        if (!includeNulls)
            enumerable = enumerable.Where(e => e != null);
        return enumerable.Select(e => (e ?? nullValue).ToString()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
object[] array = new object[] { 10, "hello", 5, "world", null };

var stringArray = array.ToStringArray();
// stringArray = { "10", "hello", "5", "world" }

stringArray = array.ToStringArray(true);
// stringArray = { "10", "hello", "5", "world", "" }

stringArray = array.ToStringArray(true, "empty");
// stringArray = { "10", "hello", "5", "world", "empty" }
```

Thanks to 280Z28 for improving the answer.

Comment: You could use the lambda `i => (i ?? string.Empty).ToString()` with `Array.ConvertAll`

Comment: Or, if you're going to use LINQ anyway, you could use `array.OfType<object>().Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()` for the original implementation of `ToStringArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
object[] input = {1, 2, null, 4, 5, 0.438, 7};
int[] result = input.OfType<int>().Select((o) => (int)o).ToArray();
// {1, 2, 4, 5, 7}
```

Or alternative going through `string` first:

```
object[] input = {1, 2, null, 4, 5, 6.438, 7};
int[] result = input.Where((o) => o != null)
    .Select((o) =>
    {
        string s = o.ToString();
        int x = 0;
        int.TryParse(s, out x);
        return x;
    }).ToArray();
// { 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 7}
```